# How to disable standalone network configuration in raspberry pi?

Tags: wifi, hostapd

I have set my raspberry pi as a standalone network using this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md). Now I want to get back to my previous normal network configuration so that I can connect to the available Wifi networks. How can I do so?

Comment: Just undo everything you did or restore from your backup

Comment: @Milliways Do I also have to change the routing and masquerade settings ? If yes then what changes do I have to make ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove packages:

```
apt-get -y remove hostapd dnsmasq bridge-utils
```

---

Comment the line below from `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

---

Reset `iptables`:

```
iptables -F
```

---

Delete following lines from `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

---

Restart the `dhcpcd` daemon:

```
sudo service dhcpcd restart
```

---

`reboot` the raspberry pi.